# 'nuget.org[https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' error

Tags: xaml

I am getting an error while creating project in VS 2019. This is what I did

1. Selected "create new project"
2. Selected "Blank App (WinUI in UWP)" and create
3. It starts creating project but then throws an error

[The feed 'nuget.org[https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists package
'runtime.win10-arm64.Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler.2.2.1' but multiple
attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again]

Tried various ways,didn't work for me. Please help.